# Are there any modern cubesats or smallsats that have relied only on magnetotorquers for attitude control?

Tags: cubesat, attitude-determination-and-control, magnetorquer, smallsat

[This comment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/38697/can-the-electric-field-of-the-earths-be-used-for-satellite-maneuvering/38698?noredirect=1#comment124838_38698) got me thinking...

**Question:** Are there any modern cubesats or smallsats that have relied only on magnetotorquers for attitude control, sans reaction wheels or thrusters?

Ideally an affirmative answer would cite an example that is or has been in orbit, but a reaonsable/credible proposal or design would do.

Answer (score 2):

[M-Cubed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-Cubed) is (was?) a cubesat build at the University of Michigan that [sort-of qualifies](https://directory.eoportal.org/web/eoportal/satellite-missions/m/m3-mcubed):

> The satellite uses a small permanent magnet and orthogonal mu-metal dampening strips as passive attitude control to slowly orient its Z axis to the Earth's polar magnetic field lines.

(It carries no other orienting hardware)

Why just "sort-of"?

> The Michigan Exploration Laboratory (MXL) suspects that the M-Cubed CubeSat, a joint project run by MXL and JPL, became magnetically conjoined to Explorer-1 Prime, a second CubeSat released at the same time, via strong onboard magnets used for passive attitude control, after deploying on October 28, 2011. This is the first non-destructive latching of two satellites.

(from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetorquer))

Comment: This definitely qualitifes as far as I'm concerned. Even though it's a permanent magnet rather than an electromagnet, it still produces a torque via the magnetic interaction with the Earth's magnetic field, and *it was in orbit.* Thanks for the speedy answer!

Comment: related magnetic questions with Michigan-based answers; [Passive attitude stabilization with magnets - are there studies based on actual flight data?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/1599/12102) and also [Could an articulated permanent magnet work as a low-power cubesat magnetotorquer? Problems?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/17641/12102)

Answer (score 1):

The ELFIN cubesats use [magnetotorquers for attitude control](https://elfin.igpp.ucla.edu/adcs).

Comment: How incredibly cool! I've just asked [Have magnetotorquers ever been used to spin-up a satellite?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/38758/12102)