# First hemispherical resonator used in spaceflight? First used on a deep space mission?

Tags: history, attitude-determination-and-control, technology, spaceflight-firsts

[This answer to *How exactly did Cassini provide rock-solid attitude control to enable high resolution low light imaging? (1.2 arcsec/pixel for narrow angle camera)*](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/55582/12102) says:

> Cassini was the first spacecraft to use a Litton Hemispherical Resonator Gyro (HRG)

but specifies "Litton". Linked in that answer is [Hemispherical Resonator Gyro: an IRU for Cassini](https://www.spiedigitallibrary.org/conference-proceedings-of-spie/2803/1/Hemispherical-Resonator-Gyro-an-IRU-for-Cassini/10.1117/12.253429.short?SSO=1)  Proc. SPIE 2803, Cassini/Huygens: A Mission to the Saturnian Systems, (7 October 1996) which says in the abstract:

> The JPL Inertial Reference Unit (IRU) is the single most sophisticated assembly on the Cassini spacecraft. At the core of the IRU is the state-of-the-art, Litton Hemispherical Resonator Gyro (HRG).

and

> The Cassini mission is the first use of an IRU for a deep space planetary mission that does not use a spun-mass sensor.

I don't know what a "spun-mass sensor" means exactly; uncertain if "spun" refers to part of a manufacturing process (e.g. [spin casting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_casting) which could certainly be [used to make metal hemispheres](https://www.google.com/search?q=metal+spun+hemisphere&tbm=isch), see also [Acme Metal Spinning](https://www.acmemetalspinning.com/)<sup>1</sup>) or to the sensor being based on a mass that is spinning.

But here I'd like to ask:

**Questions:**

1. What was the first hemispherical resonator used in spaceflight?
2. What was the first used on a deep space mission?

The following may be helpful ([hat tip to Ng Ph](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/55518/how-exactly-did-cassini-provide-rock-solid-attitude-control-to-enable-high-resol#comment185694_55582)):

- [The Hemispherical Resonator Gyro: From Wineglass to the Planets](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/55518/how-exactly-did-cassini-provide-rock-solid-attitude-control-to-enable-high-resol#comment185694_55582)

---

<sup>1</sup>no affiliation; "ACME" anything is reminiscent of the rocket-based Wile E. Coyote & Road Runner Warner Brothers cartoons. Another [example of a metal-spinning company](https://www.cmspinning.com/metal-spinning-hemispheres-and-spheres.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to both questions appears to be the same mission, depending on how you define a "deep space mission".

[image: Image showing that the first NRG in space was the NEAR mission]

If you don't consider [NEAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NEAR_Shoemaker) deep space, then it's Cassini.

> Its first mission was the NEAR program which launched the first HRG based system into space in 1996. This was quickly followed by a commercial communications satellite then the CASSNI (sic) mission to Saturn.

Source: [The Hemispherical Resonator Gyro: From Wineglass to the Planets](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/279909300_The_Hemispherical_Resonator_Gyro_From_Wineglass_to_the_Planets)

Comment: The paper is *really interesting!* "The HRG 130P Gyro: 91 systems launched (89 satellites) 12 million operating gyro hours in space with 100% mission success"